# How to remove numbers after '/' delimiter in file?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cut

I want to remove just numbers after first '`/`' in the below example . ( i.e. `22766`)

```
%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.175/22766 dst outside:192.5.5.241/53 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.175/53967 dst outside:198.41.0.4/53 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src inside:10.252.0.220/48971 dst outside:10.60.11.83/636 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src inside:10.252.0.220/33559 dst outside:10.60.11.84/636 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src inside:10.252.0.252/37021 dst outside:10.60.11.83/636 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src inside:10.252.0.252/44549 dst outside:10.60.11.84/636 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.179/48592 dst outside:202.12.27.33/53 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.179/23582 dst outside:202.12.27.33/53 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.175/27633 dst outside:192.5.5.241/53 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.175/22766 dst outside:192.5.5.241/53 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.175/13587 dst outside:192.5.5.241/53 by access-group
```

Comment: so what is your expected output? and what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following `sed` approach:

```
line="%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.175/22766 dst outside:192.5.5.241/53 by access-group"
$ echo "$line" | sed -E 's/\/[0-9]+/\//'
```

The output:

```
%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.175/ dst outside:192.5.5.241/53 by access-group
```

`-E` option, allows extended regular expressions(the same is `-r` option)

---

To get more *"solid"*(portable) and simplified solution use the following:

```
sed  's~/[0-9]*~/~' testfile
```

`~` as a delimiter in `sed` expression

Comment: whether each of those lines starts with a newline OR they are as arbitrary text(in single string) ? Can you post those lines into your question in formatted view?

Comment: The use of `-E` isn't entirely portable; some `sed` dialects use `-r` instead and some don't support either.  `sed 's%/[0-9][0-9]*%/%'` should work with any `sed`.  (Obviously remove the slash between the two final `%` separators if you don't want to retain it.)

Comment: @BhavikShah, you mean it looks like `inside:10.252.0.175()22766` ?

Answer (score 1):

@Bhavik:try: Considering your Input_file should be same as provided one.

```
awk -F"/" '{sub(/[0-9]+/,"",$2);print}' OFS="/"   Input_file
```

Setting the field separator as "/". So only sub(substitute function built-in awk) will change all the digits which are coming in the second field of Input_file.

Comment: Works Charm. Thanks!!

Comment: @BhavikShah: Glad that it worked, in stack overflow you could select your correct answer if any answer helps you or give a upvote for encouragements to people. Enjoy learning and knowledge sharing !!

Comment: "/" means I am setting field separator here, so you mean to say your field separator is different here in Input_file? we may need to tweak code as per changes then.

Comment: Yes, just wanted to check what would be the tweaks needed here?

Comment: Off course, if your Input_file changes and doesn't have "/" in it then we may need to tweak it as per your new field separator. You could try to play with it.

Comment: what could be the string for this one.

Mar 17 00:03:13   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.165(50811) ->  172.19.26.33(4902) 
Mar 17 00:03:16   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.166(54563) ->  172.19.26.33(4902) 
Mar 17 00:03:28   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.222(38071) ->  172.19.26.33(4902) 
Mar 17 00:03:41   %ASA-5-106100: access-list   permitted tcp  10.252.0.222(38074) ->  172.19.26.33(4902)

Comment: I would rather suggest to open a new thread with sample Input_file and all details in code tags please.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/..... dst/," dst")}1' file 

%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.175/ dst outside:192.5.5.241/53 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.175/ dst outside:198.41.0.4/53 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src inside:10.252.0.220/ dst outside:10.60.11.83/636 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src inside:10.252.0.220/ dst outside:10.60.11.84/636 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src inside:10.252.0.252/ dst outside:10.60.11.83/636 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src inside:10.252.0.252/ dst outside:10.60.11.84/636 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.179/ dst outside:202.12.27.33/53 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.179/ dst outside:202.12.27.33/53 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.175/ dst outside:192.5.5.241/53 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.175/ dst outside:192.5.5.241/53 by access-group
%ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.252.0.175/ dst outside:192.5.5.241/53 by access-group
```